# Handling multiple events in long-lived Lambda Function for using AWS Greengrass

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

For a project I'm using AWS Greengrass and need to read sensor data and process it in a Lambda function.
I figured out how to invoke a Lambda function by sending sensor data via MQTT and sending data from the Lambda function to AWS IoT Cloud. Now I need a long running Lambda function to collect for example some data and publish the mean to AWS IoT Cloud or another Greengrass device.

How can I collect for example 5 data points from the same subscription in one Lambda function? The function handler doesn't seem to work in a long-lived function. So, how does the lambda function realise there is a new value in the topic (a new event)?

My Code until now:

```
    # greengrassHelloWorld.py
# Demonstrates a simple publish to a topic using Greengrass core sdk
# Since the function is
# long-lived it will run forever when deployed to a Greengrass core.  The handler
# will NOT be invoked in our example since the we are executing an infinite loop.

import time
import greengrasssdk
import platform
import json


# Creating a greengrass core sdk client
client = greengrasssdk.client('iot-data')

# When deployed to a Greengrass core, this code will be executed immediately
# as a long-lived lambda function.  The code will enter the infinite while loop
# below.


def greengrass_mean():
    while True:
        #following line just for testing 
        client.publish(topic='data/mean', payload='Mean :'+str(i))
        while i<5:
            msg='{}'.format(event['temperatur'])
            actualValue=int(msg)
            client.publish(topic='data/actulValue', payload='actual value: '+msg)
            value += actualValue
            i = i+1
        mean=actualValue/5
        client.publish(topic='data/mean', payload='Mean: '+str(mean))

i = 0

# Execute the function above
greengrass_mean()


def function_handler(event, context):
    return null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are to use a long lived lambda function, instead of reading in the data when the function is triggered, you would have to access all the device shadows you wish to gain data from sequentially say every 30 seconds or so using client.get_thing_shadow() for each device.